# Scrapy: Itemloader Processor / Method TypeError: 'ItemMeta' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I'm trying to build a function (clean_keyboard) to use in the extended Itemloader Class. 
It should filter and clean data in the extended Item Class 'category' = 'Notebook'. 
I have tested it without the filter for 'Notebooks' -> (if ProductItem['category'] == 'Notebook':) and the Processor/Method works fine without. But after inserting this piece of code for filtering I get the TypeError above in the title. See code below.

```
### processor method for cleaning data with the Itemloader, Item and Itemloader class extended

def clean_keyboard(pattern):
    keyboard_dict = {'deutsch': 'DE', 'US-QWERTY': 'US', '': 'DE'} 

    if ProductItem['category'] == 'Notebook': # <-- TypeError when adding category filter, without it works fine
       if pattern in keyboard_dict:
            return keyboard_dict[pattern] 
        else:
            return pattern

class ProductItem(scrapy.Item):
    category = scrapy.Field()
    keyboard = scrapy.Field()

class SpiderItemLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_item_class = ProductItem
    default_input_processor = MapCompose(str.strip)
    default_output_processor = TakeFirst()

    keyboard_out = MapCompose(clean_keyboard)


### Parse Method in the Spider to get the data/ using the SpiderItemloader extended class

def parse_item(self, response):

    l = SpiderItemLoader(response = response)

    l.add_xpath('keyboard', '//*[@class="short-description"]/p/strong[text()="keyboard"]/following-sibling::text()')
    l.add_xpath('category', '//*[@class="short-description"]/p/strong[text()="category"]/following-sibling::text()'')

    return l.load_item()
```

Comment: ProductItem is a class. Presumably you need an instance, then you would access it via `product_item.category`.

Comment: Hi Daniel, can you provide some code examples related to the method code above, thanks

Comment: No, because I don't know anything about Scrapy. But I don't think your code makes any sense. Where is the relevant ProductItem supposed to be coming from?

Comment: no problem, thanks anyway. But it does make sense, since it works without the category filter. -> ProductItem is being populated from the item collected with the Spider selector, see https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Daniel commented, the failing line makes no sense. You want to inspect the 'category' property of the item being processed, however your `clean_keyboard` function has no access to it. `ProductItem` is a class shared by all items, not a specific item.

Item loader processors have no access to items, only to a specific property of those.

I recommend that you use an [item pipeline](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html) instead of an item loader processor to implement the logic of your `clean_keyboard` function.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, thank you both for helping me understanding this with the class access (Itemloader vs. Item Pipeline).

Thus, since I do have access to items in Item Pipeline I was able to solve the filtering, accesing other item by using the Item Pipeline. See my tested code with the solution below.

```
# Configure item pipelines in settings.py

ITEM_PIPELINES = {
   'tutorial.pipelines.DataCleaningPipeline': 300,
}

# Pipeline in pipelines.py

class DataCleaningPipeline(object):

    def process_item(self, item, spider):

        keyboard_dict = {'deutsch': 'DE', 'US-QWERTY': 'US', '': 'DE', 'QWERTZ': 'DE'} 

        dict_key = item.get('keyboard')
        category = item.get('category')

        if 'Notebook' in category and dict_key in keyboard_dict:
            item['keyboard']= keyboard_dict[dict_key]
            return item 
        else:
            return item
```